# Comparing the expectations of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

Let $X,Y$ be nonzero independent random variables, and $X$ has zero expectation. Let the distributions of $X,Y$ be $\mu,\nu$ respectively. Problem gives a condition that $$0 < \lim_{x\to 0+} \frac{\nu(-x,x)}{x} = a< \infty$$ Define $Z_n = X/(|Y| + 1/n)$ and let $Z = \lim_n Z_n$. The problem is to compare the expectations of $Z_n$'s and $Z$.

For $Z_n$, since $E\frac{1}{|Y| + 1/n} \leq E[n] = n < \infty$, we have $$E \frac{X}{|Y| + 1/n} = EX \cdot E\frac{1}{|Y|+1/n} = 0$$ since both expectations are finite. However, in the case of $Z$, We can't say that $EZ = 0$ since $E\frac{1}{|Y|}$ need not be finite. My try is to use transformation theorem and Fubini's theorem: $$E \frac{X}{|Y|} = \int_{\mathbb R^2} \frac{x}{|y|} d (\mu \otimes\nu) = \int_{\mathbb R} \int_{\mathbb R} \frac{x}{|y|} d\mu(x) d\nu(y)$$ but we cannot further separate the integrals since they are not guaranteed to be finite. How can I deal with such a situation? What can be the meaning of the condition $0 < \lim_{x\to 0+} \frac{\nu(-x,x)}{x} =a< \infty$?

Thanks in advance for any form of help, hint, or solution.

Comment: Not sure how $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\nu(-x,x)}x$ could be anything else than $0$ since $\nu(-x,x)\le1$. Perhaps you meant $\lim_{x\to0^+}$?

Comment: @nejimban Yes, it should be the limit to 0. Sorry.

Comment: Since $\Bbb E\frac1{|Y|}=\int_0^\infty\frac{\nu(-x,x)}{x^2}\,\mathrm dx$, I would say one needs a slightly stronger assumption to have finite expectation…

Comment: @nejimban Where does the extra factor of $x$ come from in the denominator of that expression?

Comment: @nejimban I think that this might be the point exactly of the exercise: to have an example where the sequence does not converge in expectation.

Comment: @user6247850 $\Bbb E{\frac1{|Y|}}=\int_0^\infty\Bbb P\left(\frac1{|Y|}>t\right)\mathrm d t$ and perform the change of variable $x\gets\frac1t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $0<\varepsilon<1$,
\begin{align*}
\Bbb E\,{\frac1{|Y|}}
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{\nu(-x,x)}{x^2}\,\mathrm dx\\[.4em]
&\ge\int_{\varepsilon^2}^\varepsilon\frac{\nu(-x,x)}{x^2}\,\mathrm dx\\[.4em]
&\ge\left(\inf_{\varepsilon^2\le x\le\varepsilon}\frac{\nu(-x,x)}x\right)\int_{\varepsilon^2}^\varepsilon\frac{\mathrm dx}x\\[.4em]
&\ge\left(\inf_{0<x\le\varepsilon}\frac{\nu(-x,x)}x\right)\log\left(\frac1{\varepsilon}\right),
\end{align*}
so
$$\Bbb E\,\frac1{|Y|}\ge\underbrace{\liminf_{x\to0^+}\frac{\nu(-x,x)}x}_{{}>0}\cdot\left[\lim_{x\to0^+}\log\left(\frac1x\right)\right]=\infty.$$
This is equivalent to $\Bbb E\,|Z|=\infty$ because $\Bbb E\,|X|\in(0,\infty)$ ($X$ is nonzero and has finite expectation).

In fact, one can see that a necessary and sufficient condition for $\Bbb E\,\frac1{|Y|}<\infty$ is that $\frac{\nu(-x,x)}{x^2}$ be integrable at $0^+$, so that $\nu(-x,x)$ decays slightly faster than $x$ (e.g., $\nu(-x,x)=O(x/{\log^2x})$ would work).

Comment: Thanks! Now I see the expectation of $|Z|$ is infinite. Is there a statement able to said about the expectation of $Z$ (or $|Z_n|$)?

Comment: The expectation of $Z$ can only be defined if $\Bbb E\,|Z|<\infty$. For $|Z_n|$, one has $\Bbb E\,|Z_n|\le n\,\Bbb E\,|X|<\infty$ (as you showed), but $\lim_{n\to\infty}\Bbb E\,|Z_n|=\infty$ by Fatou's lemma (or the monotone convergence theorem).

Comment: I think we should understand “$X$ nonzero” as $\Bbb P(X\neq 0)>0$. The broader meaning (there exists $\omega$ such that $X(\omega)\neq0$) would allow $X=0$ almost surely and in this case $Z_n$ and $Z$ would be almost surely zero as well.